# Erro de token mismatch no laravel

Tags: laravel

Meu formulário de login funciona corretamente:

```
<form action="{{route('autenticacao.logar')}}" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="text" name="cpf" class="form-control" placeholder="CPF" style="border-radius:10px; border-color:blue;" />
    <br/>
    <input type="password" name="senha" class="form-control" placeholder="senha" style="border-radius:10px; border-color:blue;" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" value="Entrar" />
</form>
```

Porém, se eu fizer logoff:

```
public function logout(){
    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();

    return view('autenticacao.login');
}
```

Quando tento refazer o login, recebo erro:

> TokenMismatchException
>   in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68

Mas se eu atualizar a página funciona normalmente, porém é chato pro usuário ter que atualizar a página sempre que quiser fazer login novamente.

O que pode ser?

Comment: Você precisa dar um `redirect` nesse caso, ou seja, não carrega nada nessa parte, porque ao dar um logout e limpa os dados de `session`.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não entendi bem. Porque não posso dar logout já que minha intenção é justamente limpar os dados?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, consegui resolver sim, fazendo uma busca por redirect e logout, obrigado

Comment: é que nesse caso em especifico você mandou limpar toda a sessão e no mesmo momento carregou uma `view` e isso não gera a `csrf token`, por isso eu disse precisa dar um `redirect` para que seja gerado novamente os dados ...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic entendi. resolveu meu problema